# SalesForce Marketing Cloud - Any way to assign a campaign to an email template via SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm using the c# library for the ET SOAP API and I'm trying to assign a campaign ID to email templates.  However, this doesn't appear to be possible.  Going by [this documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/email/), I don't see a property to set that would associate a campaign.  Are there any workarounds to this limitation?  Campaigns can be associated to email content in the Marketing Cloud UI, so I assumed there would be a way to do so via the API.

[I do see](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/) that I can assign a campaign to an email send definition through the 'additional' property.  So I'm guessing that's all that matters in terms of campaign associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Campaigns aren't available in the SOAP API. There is a 'Campaigns' object in the SOAP API, but this isn't what you think it is — this refers to a deprecated 'Programs' feature which will be sunset in early 2017.

### REST API Method

You will need to use the REST API to assign a campaign to one or more assets (e.g. an email, Data Extension, Automation or other type). Refer to the [associateAssetToCampaign](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/campaigns/associateAssetToCampaign.html) method.

> **Note:** the request payload documented in the link above is slightly confusing. The `301` value in the URL refers to the Campaign ID that you are assigning an asset (or assets) to.

### C# Fuel SDK

As you are using C#, you can optionally use the [C# SDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/csharp/getting-started-with-the-csharp-sdk.html) to associate asset(s) to a campaign. Refer to [this documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/campaign-assets/campaign-asset-create.html#csharpget).

> **Note**: the documentation states that this operation is used for 'to create a new campaign within a Marketing Cloud account', which is completely incorrect; you can ignore this description.